# Select all the text in an input, focusin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have all the text selected when I give the focus to an element.

I used

```
$('.class-focusin').focusin(function(e) {
    $(this).select();
});
```

But it's not the perfect behavior I want. When i click between two characters, the input value is not seleted, there is a cursor in the middle.
I want the behavior of the url bar in chrome browser: you click and the cursor is replaced by the value selection

Feel free to test my problem in this fiddle:
 http://jsfiddle.net/XS6s2/8/

I want the text to be able to receive the cursor once selected.
The answer selected, below is definitely what I wanted, Thanks

Comment: just follow the fiddle.

Comment: Do you want people to be able to click a second time, to position the cursor? Then a simple click event would be out, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a variable to see if the text has been selected or not:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/XS6s2/21/

```
var has_focus = false;
$('.class-focusin').click(function(e) {
    if(!has_focus) {
        $(this).select();
        has_focus = true;
    }
 });

$('.class-focusin').blur(function(e) {
   has_focus = false; 
});
```

Comment: it's perfect it allows to tab in aswell

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to wait for the browser to give focus to the element, then do your selection:

```
$('.class-focusin').focus(function(e) { 
    var $elem = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
    $elem.select();
    }, 1);
 });
```

Yuck. Or simply bind to the click event instead:

```
$('.class-focusin').click(function(e) { 
    $(this).select();
 });
```

Comment: Using `0` as the timeout would be more appropriate – either way though I agree with your "yuck" assestment :)

Comment: the problem with click is you lose the ability to tab in..was trying to work a click + focusin double header, since focusin works fine when you tab in..

Comment: @jenson-button-event Very good point. I guess for that scenario using a timeout is the way to go, ugly though it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try using click instead of focusin.

```
$('.class-focusin').click(function(e) {
    $(this).select();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Narcotic/XS6s2/20/)

Bye!

Comment: It's not what i want, when I click again in the selected text, it doesn't enable the cursor

Answer (score 0):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/XS6s2/22/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.class-focusin').click(function (e) {

        $(this).select();

    });
});
```

Comment: It's not what i want, when I click again in the selected text, it doesn't enable the cursor

Answer (score 0):

It's a direct duplicate of [Select all the text in an input, focusin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717265/select-all-the-text-in-an-input-focusin/17717379#17717379), here's a nice answer from it

```
$(".class-focusin").on("focus",function(e){
    $(this).select();
});

$(".class-focusin").on("mouseup",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XS6s2/31/

Comment: It's not what i want, when I click again in the selected text, it doesn't enable the cursor